# Change "onclick" Event (Input type = button) in IE 8/9 & FF with jQuery won´t work (IE doesn´t recognize the change)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, onclick

```
<input id="UploadButton" type="button" value="Upload" onclick="xyz"/> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetList",
            listName: "Docs",
            async: false,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                id = $(xData.responseXML).find("List").attr("ID");
            }
        });

        reference = "./_layouts/Upload.aspx?List=" + id + "&amp;RootFolder=";
        $('#UploadButton2').attr("href", reference);
        alert($('#UploadButton2').attr("href"));

        js = "javascript:" + "NewItem2(event, &quot;" + reference + "&quot;);javascript:return false;";
        $('#UploadButton').attr("onclick", js);
        alert($('#UploadButton').attr("onclick"));
    });
</script>
```

I've found several things or solutions they would fit to my problem but it won't work.

I just want to set or change the "onclick"-Event for the Input type (id=UploadButton) and

```
alert($('#UploadButton').attr("onclick"));
```

gives me the string from "js". So far so good... But if I click on the UploadButton nothing happens. It seems that the browser won't recognize the change. The solution in my current code ins´t the only one I tried out over last few hours. One of the solutions I've tried was to use so .click() method of jQuery, but I can´t call the "NewItem2()" function over .click(), do I?
My primary target is to call the "NewItem2()" function over the UploadButton with the information of the string "reference". Unfortunately NewItem2() is a function of Sharepoint so there is no code inside written with my hands but if I set the attribute onclick hard in the code, the button is working perfectly :-/

I've seen so many different solutions over the last time but nothing won't fit for me but I think the failure is on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your call to NewItem2 as a string, you will have better luck changing

```
js = "javascript:" + "NewItem2(event, &quot;" + reference + "&quot;);javascript:return false;";
$('#UploadButton').attr("onclick", js);
```

to

```
$('#UploadButton').click( function (event) {
    NewItem2(event, reference);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the `onclick` event for that button you will need to either bind an anonymous function:

```
$( '#UploadButton' ).click( function () {
    // Do stuff here
} );
```

... or bind another named function:

```
$( '#UploadButton' ).click( myClickHandler );
```

Comment: I already tried the .click() Method but can I call the NewItem2() funtion from there? If I try to call the function as usual nothing happens or an error comes up.

Comment: Good question... As I said the NewItem2 is not written with my hands but I would say yes, because I can call the function over every href or input button in HTML. There is no specific error but the script won´t load or nothing in the <script>-tags take any effect.